# does independence relation hold for autocovariance in a time series context

Tags: time-series

I've been wondering the following for a while because it comes up on the dsp exchange site that I also belong to. Maybe it's obvious but not to me. Background: Clearly,  If $x$ and $y$ are independent random variables, then it is well known and pretty easy to show that $var(\alpha_1 x + \alpha_2 y ) = \alpha_1^2 \times  var(x) + \alpha_2^2 \times var(y) $.

Actual Question: Does the same  relation  hold for autocovariances of the same variables in a time series context ? By this I mean that, if the same two variables are still independent, then does $cov(\alpha_1 x + \alpha_2 y )$ at lag $i$ = $ \alpha_1^2 \times $ ( autocov($x$) at lag i ) $ + \alpha_2^2  \times $ ( autocov($y$) at lag i)  ? Thanks. Any references or useful notes are also appreciated.

Comment: Are your two variables independent contemporaneously only ($X_t$ independent of $Y_t$ for all $t$), or also at all leads and lags ($X_t$ independent from $Y_{t-i}$, for all $t$ and $i$)?

Comment: Hi Chris.  Yes, $X_t$ and $Y_t$ can be considered independent at all lags. ( i.e: they only have auto-correlation and not cross-correlation ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the time dependence more explicit, I'll define:

$$Z_t := \alpha_1X_t + \alpha_2Y_t$$

We're looking for the autocovariance function of $Z_t$:

$$\text{Cov}(Z_t,Z_{t-i})=\text{Cov}(\alpha_1X_t + \alpha_2Y_t, \alpha_1X_{t-i} + \alpha_2Y_{t-i})$$

By the bilinearity property of the covariance, we can start by expanding the first term, and then the second:

\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(\alpha_1X_t + \alpha_2Y_t, \alpha_1X_{t-i} + \alpha_2Y_{t-i}) &= \alpha_1\text{Cov}(X_t, \alpha_1X_{t-i} + \alpha_2Y_{t-i}) \\
&+ \alpha_2\text{Cov}(Y_t, \alpha_1X_{t-i} + \alpha_2Y_{t-i}) \\
\\
&= \alpha_1^2 \text{Cov}(X_t,X_{t-i})+\alpha_1\alpha_2\text{Cov}(X_t,Y_{t-i})\\
&+ \alpha_2\alpha_1\text{Cov}(Y_t, X_{t-i}) + \alpha_2^2\text{Cov}(Y_t,Y_{t-i})
\end{align}

If the two series are independent at all lags, then the two cross terms $\text{Cov}(X_t,Y_{t-i})$ and $\text{Cov}(Y_t,X_{t-i})$ are both zero for any $i$ and $t$, so the result is, as you have claimed, that:

$$\text{Cov}(Z_t, Z_{t-i}) =\alpha_1^2 \text{Cov}(X_t,X_{t-i})+\alpha_2^2\text{Cov}(Y_t,Y_{t-i})$$

Comment: Thanks Chris. It looks clear and really useful. I will print out and make sure that  I follow it.

Comment: Hi Chris: You derivation was crystal clear. And the correlation at lag i would be the covariance at lag i  divided by square root of [product of the variances] which would mean the denominator would  just be $Var(Z_{t})$. Great stuff.

Comment: That would require the variance to be constant over time ($\text{Var}(Z_t)=\text{Var}(Z_{t-i})$ for all $t$ and $i$), but if you're willing to assume that then yes, that's correct.

Comment: Hi: yeah, I would think stationary variance is an okay assumption. if not, then there are all sorts of new problems that get introduced. Thanks again.